# Assign value to one property change another property value

Tags: c#

Please need some clarification on the below.
Also if you don't mind some C# low level explanation and/or books on the matter please.

Why after assigning value to **secondDog.breed** property (3rd line), both properties got the same value (firstDog.Breed and secondDog.Breed).

Seems like only secondDog that is supposed to display "Labrador", not firstDog !!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var firstDog = new Dog() { Breed = "Bulldog" };
        var secondDog = firstDog;

        secondDog.Breed = "Labrador";   // Magic happens here !!!

        Console.WriteLine(firstDog.Breed);      // Labrador (why ???)
        Console.WriteLine(secondDog.Breed);     // Labrador
    }
    
    class Dog
    {
        public string Breed { get; set; }
    }
```

Why on the below code I get different result than on the above code (Dog example)

```
int num = 5;
int numb = num;

numb = 30;

Console.WriteLine(num);    // 5  (Not 30 like in the above Dog example)
Console.WriteLine(numb);   // 30
```

Comment: The `Dog` class is a reference type. You only created one dog. `firstDog` and `secondDog` contain two different references to the same `Dog` instance. Integers are value types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between reference types and value types in action.

Value type holds a data value within its own memory space. It means that a variable contains a value.

```
int num = 5; // value type. We have created a value in memory
int numb = num; // here numb is 5. It is not pointing to `num`
    // it just copies value of `num`. `numb` has own value 5 in 
    // memory. We created the second value in memory. Here we have 
    // two values in memory.

numb = 30; // here num is 30
```

However, reference type doesn't store its value directly. It stores the address where the value is stored.That is reference type has a pointer to another memory location that holds the data.

```
var firstDog = new Dog() { Breed = "Bulldog" }; // reference type
// We've created one object in memory
var secondDog = firstDog; // here you are assigning reference of 
    // "firstDog" to "secondDog". We still have one object on 
    // memory. We have not created new object in memory

secondDog.Breed = "Labrador";   // Here you are reading the address 
    // of object which points to the object created in the first row of 
    // this code snippet
```

[Read more about difference between reference type and value type here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)